# jQuery: replace image with div on hover

Tags: jquery, replace, hover, mouseover, mouseout

I hope there is anybody who can help me! :)

I wrote a small jquery script **replacing** all the **img** tags on my site with **div** tags. I take the image source as the divs background image and the image width and height as the divs width and height. That is working fine.

Now I want to replace the div (*var nohover*) with another div (*var hover*) on mouseover and back to the first div (*var nohover*) on mouseout. How can I achieve that? I am dying here.

thanks in advance and hello from germany!

much love!

jaro

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this),
      href = $img.attr('src');
    width = $img.attr('width');
    height = $img.attr('height');
    wbgclass = $img.attr("class");

    var nohover = '<div class="wbg-image-container ' + wbgclass + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;"><div class="wbg-image" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4)), url(' + href + '); background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4)), url(' + href + '); background-size: auto, cover;"></div></div>';

    var hover = '<div class="wbg-image-container ' + wbgclass + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;"><div class="wbg-image" style="background-image: url(' + href + '); background-image: url(' + href + '); background-size: auto, cover;"></div></div>';

    $img.replaceWith(nohover);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="soz.jpg" width="269" height="358" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: You might find jQuery's [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery .hover() method:

```
$img.hover(function() {
  $('.container').html(hover);
});
```

[Here is a codepen demonstrating the .hover() functionality](http://codepen.io/mdan89/pen/RPJMpY)

If you want to be more specific you can also use **.mouseenter()** and **.mouseleave()** as the **.hover()** method runs on both **.mouseenter()** and **.mouseleave()**

So your methods would look like :

```
$img.mouseenter(function() {
    $('.container').html(hover);
});

$img.mouseleave(function() {
    $('.container').html(nohover);
});
```

Comment: i managed to get it working for one img elemtn now. but immediately after adding a second image to the page, everything explodes..

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. Also encase the `img` element inside a parent element as you are replacing the content and bind the events to the container.

Here is a rough example of what you might do..

```
var href,
width,
height,
wbgclass;

$('.item').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    href = $('img', $this).attr('src');
    width = $('img', $this).attr('width');
    height = $('img', $this).attr('height');
    wbgclass = $('img', $this).attr("class");



    var hover = '<div class="wbg-image-container ' + wbgclass + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;"><div class="wbg-image" style="background-image: url(' + href + '); background-image: url(' + href + '); background-size: auto, cover;"></div></div>';


});


$('.item').on('mouseout', function (e) {
    var nohover = '<div class="wbg-image-container ' + wbgclass + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;"><div class="wbg-image" style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4)), url(' + href + '); background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 253, 0.4)), url(' + href + '); background-size: auto, cover;"></div></div>';

    $(this).replaceWith(nohover);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ys4fmwd/)**

Comment: will this work for only one img element or for every element on the page? i was trying to replace all img tags with divs. i thought i would have to use the .each function then.

Comment: @buntestrahlen You need not use the `each` in this case. The way events are bound will take care of it. Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/6ys4fmwd/1/ . The only thing that I added is extra images.

Comment: your starting the function via a class called `item`. do i have to add this class to every image on the page i want to replace?

Comment: oh! i see. its added to the div wrapping the img tags. but how can i wrap every img on my page with that div?

Comment: it simply does not work. even if i wrap my img tags inside the div with a class called `item` by myself on a test page… the hover mouseover event work but the mouseout event doesnt! can anyone explain that to me? :)